# windows phone application set up in xamarin studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am going to start a job portal application using xamarin.forms library. This application will be a cross platform application. But it was very easy to set up project for iOS and android but for window i did not get any clue how to configure xamarin studio for windows phone. Can any one tell me how to set up my project for windows phone in xamarin studio?

Comment: Did you get any useful answer of your question? I'm also looking out for an answer of this same question.

Comment: I have read so many articles and come to conclusion that for windows app i have to use windows machine with xamarin.visual studio.

Comment: I've installed "xamarin.visual studio" but as I have express edition of VS so I did not get any extension or plugin in VS. So I guess one needs to install visual studio ultimate edition to get things work for windows phone application.

Comment: You need business edition for xamarin plugin .

Comment: Have you tried "VS 2013 Community Edition" as per the below answer? Is it working?

Comment: Silpa actully i am out from work since few days and right now i have no windows machine but i will try to help you in same very soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71230/discussion-between-shilpa-soni-and-vinit-saxena).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin Studio doesn't support Windows Phone :(

You will need to install VisualStudio... There is free version of VS called VS 2013 Community Edition, but check conditions if you can use it.

You can still develop PCL, Android and iOS projects in Xamarin Studio and WP project in VS.

Comment: David you means i have to develop iOS and Android app on Mac and WP project on VS?

Comment: Yes, but Android can be developed either on Windows or Mac inside Xamarin Studio...
Notice that Xamarin.VisualStudio supports all three platforms development on Windows(you still need Mac on same network for building iOS) but it requires Business edition.